# Pinning different programs to each virtual desktop's taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, virtual-desktop

I use Mark Russinovich's [Desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881) to organize my windows in my work computer. Is it possible to pin different programs to each virtual desktop's taskbar?

For example:

- **Desktop 1:** Chrome, Windows Explorer, Visual Studio 2010

[image]

- **Desktop 2:** Chrome, Windows Explorer, SQL Server Management Studio

[image]

- **Desktop 3:** Chrome, Windows Explorer, custom apps

[image]

- **Desktop 4:** Chrome, Windows Explorer, Visual Basic 6

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so. Because the last Explorer closed will overwrite all other's settings... I don't think Desktops provides a functionality to set apart the configurations through restarts yet.

Comment: The taskbar pins are stored per-user (partly on disk and partly in the registry), not 'per desktop'. So, as you say, the last changes made (regardless of which Desktop object is active when you do it) will be what's reflected the next time your 'desktop is prepared' during boot.  Also, from what I can tell, the pins re at least partially controlled by Internet Explorer and not Explorer, so just restarting Explorer doesn't reflect changes made outside of the actual 'pinning' routines/actions (i.e.: going and deleting the 'pin' shortcuts manually off the disk will not reflect until you reboot).

Comment: This extends my answer by a good bit :). But I don't think this is managed by Internet Explorer... The times of Active Desktop implemented in Internet Explorer are over in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, you'd think so, except the on-disk path the pins are held in is "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar". From my understanding, the pinning is an extension of the Quick Launch, which was introduced with IE4.  Plus, as I said, (just) restarting Explorer isn't enough for it to properly reflect changes to the pins, so it seems there's (still) other elements involved.  I guess we'd have to ask MS to be sure. ;)

Comment: @techie007 oooh, more Microsoft voodoo!

Answer (score 1):

[Desktops](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881) is an app that can do what you describe. It's only 60 kB.

One of its shortages is that you can not transfer apps between different desktops.

Comment: Read the question: "I use Mark Russinovich's Desktops to organize my windows in my work computer. Is it possible to pin different programs to each virtual desktop's taskbar?". So he already uses Desktops.